# jQuery AJAX call to certain file causes call stack size exceeded error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a really strange problem in my code. The following AJAX call to file `abs_value.php` freezes the browser for a couple of seconds and then fails with a call stack size exceeded error.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'abs_value.php',
    type: 'get',
    data: { 
        gas: gas, 
        st_id: "" , 
        date: date1, 
        hour: time
    },
    success: function(data) {  
        window.alert(data); 
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        window.alert(error);
    }
});
```

abs_value.php

```
<?php
    //code for database connection here
    $gas = $_GET["gas"];
    $station = $_GET["st_id"];
    $date = $_GET["date"];
    $hour = $_GET["hour"];

    if (!empty($station)) 
    {
        $sql = "some sql query";
    } 
    else
    {
        $sql = "another sql query";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while ($obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
    {
        $var[] = $obj;
    }
    echo json_encode($var);
?>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var req2="req2";
         $.ajax({ 
                  url: 'stats.php',
                  data: 'req='+req2,
                  type: 'post',
                  success: function(data){alert("request 2")}
               });
        });
    </script>
```

I know that both queries work and this is supposed to be an infinite loop
problem, however, I can't really find what causes it. Any help would
be greatly appreciated!

Comment: we need to see more of your javascript, there is a loop some where in there which you are not showing us with your current code.

Comment: oops! forgot to add some javascript from the second file. edited my question! hope it helps alhtough i dont think that's the problem. let me say also that the ajax request is in an if statement and its the only call in the statement

Comment: "this is supposed to be an infinite loop problem"? What do you mean?

Comment: From what I've read on several similar problems, the "call stack size exceeded" error is caused by an infinite loop somewhere in the code. But I have no such loop or I'm failing to see it